# How to overlay a button image over a button object?

Tags: android, image, button

I have added an image resource for a button in an activity but the Android button object appears bigger than the image resource as shown here: https://plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/AH4B1pvbTeM

As you can see the grey background is the button object appearing from behind the image resource.
I want the button image to overlay the button but when I try to re size it,it stays the same dimension.Does anyone have a solution to this problem?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
android:layout_width="200dp"
android:layout_height="50dp"
android:background="@drawable/image_name"
```

// Use fixed value Or Put the all type of image with fix size in drawable-hdpi, mdpi,xhdpi, ldpi

Comment: In plain English: use that image as the background rather than the foreground.

Comment: I tried this but when I change the size of the button my button image becomes smaller also.Is there a setting that is linking the image resource to the button size?

Answer (score 1):

If you will use ImageButton instead of button image background was overlay

Comment: Okay,so this is how I tried to implement your explanation : plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/4nzPiFkV3rr And this is what it turned out like,still not correct: plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/jgNSe53XDcT

Comment: You has syntaxis mistake, rename "imagebutton" to "ImageButton" and try again

Answer (score 0):

Use ImageButton as the element, and also set the attribute android:scaleType="fitXY"

Comment: Okay,so this is how I tried to implement your explanation : https://plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/4nzPiFkV3rr And this is what it turned out like,still not correct:  https://plus.google.com/112628117356947034778/posts/jgNSe53XDcT